# Did Hitler really keep the blueprints of the current Nebraska state Capitol building in the drawer of his desk?

Tags: world-war-two, hitler

I recently stumbled upon [an article](http://www.blacktable.com/munson040616.htm) in the now-defunct lit mag Black Table in which the author establishes the un-cited claim that Hitler had designs on making Lincoln, Nebraska the new headquarters for the ENTIRE Third Reich were the Nazis ever to invade and conquer the United States. The article claims that Hitler admired the design of the [Nebraska state Capitol building](http://capitol.nebraska.gov/index.php/building/history/nebraska-capitols) (designed by German-American architect Bertram Goodhue) over all other American monuments and landmarks, and even kept a copy of the blueprints stored in his desk. Owing to Lincoln's centralized geographic location, Hitler also thought it would serve well as the seat of his entire empire.

Can any WWII historians out there attest to even a shred of credibility for this claim?

Comment: hmmmm....interesting, I have always heard that the state capitol building was a place for Baal worshiping (Satan worshipers)  I thought it was just an urban legend.  I will have to do some research :)

Comment: I find no evidence that Goodhue was of German-American heritage; [Lee Lawrie](http://capitol.nebraska.gov/building/history/team/lee-lawrie/), the sculptor was born in Germany.  I'm deeply suspicious of this claim; even the article you reference only says "as the story goes".  Snopes has nothing, google has nothing other than the article.  Absent evidence, I think we have to write this off as local urban legend.

Comment: @steelerfan Yeah, I was a Lincolnite until recently, and it was a big inside joke in town that the UNL honors society, the Society of Innocents, was a satanist cult. I would sometimes see the public aspects of their rituals while walking around campus, and, if I didn't know better, I could see how people would view their aesthetics as iffy: red hooded robes, 13 members, group logo is the head of mephistopheles, etc. The Capitol-as-baal-worshiping temple comes from the fact that SoI holds their annual initiation ceremony in some hideaway antechamber below the dome every year around Easter.

Comment: I recently read an article claiming Hitler, after conquering the United States, planned to send Goebbels to Los Angeles to fix up dates with Betty Grable and Jane Russel. Drugs will do that to a person.

Comment: Hitler wrote in 'The Secret Diaries': 'After I conquer the United States, I will order Doktor Goebbels, to fix up dates with Betty Grable and Jane Russel.'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are asking to prove a negative here which is not really possible. Who knows what was rattling around in Hitler's brain? Just because a bunch of clowns in the OSS found some blueprints in one of his desks doesn't prove he was plotting to take over Nebraska. Hitler was an architecture freak who spent hours going over the details of buildings with [Speer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Speer), his lead architect. He had lots of blueprints. There is nothing in either of Speer's two books about Hitler plotting to move the capital of the Third Reich to Nebraska, nor is there any such thing that I know of in the Tischensprach either (although I have not read the whole Tischensprach).

The idea that Hitler, a fanatic German nationalist, would move the capital out of Germany is not logical in any way. Moreover, Hitler had plans to build a gigantic super city, called [Welthauptstadt Germania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welthauptstadt_Germania) (in GERMANY obviously) which featured a huge 950-foot building, called the [Volkshalle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkshalle), so big you could fit the great pyramid inside its dome. Doesn't sound like somebody getting ready to move to Nebraska. Welthauptstadt means "world capital".

Comment: He's not asking to prove a negative. He's looking for corroborating evidence to a claim made in what was supposed to be a factual article. The second paragraph was more helpful and on-track as to why such corroborating evidence cannot be found.